# How do I search for records in a table using a procedure in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to...

1. Ask user for input and store the input to a variable
2. Pass this variable into a procedure
3. Procedure then should iterate through every row in one column of a certain table
4. If the variable matches then all columns for that row will be printed out via. DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
5. Procedure continues to iterate through all rows until finished

I've tried reading my course-material, but the procedures being created are for different uses (e.g. updating a column in a row when a 'where' condition is met) and I'm struggling to understand how to use a procedure to do what I'm trying to do.

The table 'Vehicles' has rows 'v_regno'(PK), 'v_make', 'v_model', 'v_year' etc.

Here's the code.

```
/*Procedure to search for car by make*/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SaleByMake(
    search_make IN VARCHAR2(15)
)
IS  
BEGIN
    FOR /*each row in 'Items' table*/
        IF i_make = search_make THEN
        /*Print out columns of this row*/

        END IF;
    END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN /*What goes in here?*/

END;

-- Get Input from User
ACCEPT search_make CHAR(15) PROMPT 'Enter car make: ';

-- Call the SaleByMake() Procedure and check stock amount status of item
EXECUTE SaleByMake(&search_make);
```

Comment: looks like you need a CURSOR, a WHILE LOOP, you don't need to catch the exception if you're not going to do anything with it, and you need to add the DBMS_OUTPUT

Comment: For the "What goes in here?" bit, you can put a `DBMS_OUTPUT` line there if you wish, referencing the handy Oracle built-in function `SQLERRM` to see what the actual error message is. As Randy said, you don't really need an exception handler for this one unless you want it. Note that this handler will swallow all excepetions, kind of like Java "catch (Throwable t)", possibly hiding problems.

Answer (score 0):

is that what you Need?

```
/*Procedure to search for car by make*/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SaleByMake(
    search_make IN VARCHAR2
)
IS  
BEGIN
    FOR rec in (select col1,col2,col3 from table where col = search_make )
    Loop
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.col1||' ' || rec.col2||' ' ||rec.col3);
    END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN /*What goes in here?*/

END;
```

you should replace the select the table Name a column names with names you need

Comment: you are using a cursor not correct in a loop. compare your code and my code. replace my select by your select statement. you do not need to declare rec as variable

Comment: Parameters don't have precision/scale. Exception handlers are optional.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/4BYDY5w.png
I think I've got the hang of it now.
I can get the procedure to compile without any errors, however, when I try to use it to search for a make of car I get the following error codes:
ORA-06550, PLS-00201 'identifier 'MAZDA' must be declared'
@hotfix

Comment: your procedure expect a string, so you shoul also pass a string as parameter. `execute SaleByMake('&search_make');`